# permission denied when sudo chown

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I have a folder, wich I used once (successfully) to have a /dev/null directory (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1788357/sink-file-like-dev-null/1788359#1788359)), and after trying to mount again after `fusermount -u`, I get permission denied. asin:

```
$ sudo su
# cd /home
# ls -ld user
drwxr-xr-x 23 user user 12288 jun 11 08:13 user
# cd user
# ls -ld null
ls: cannot access 'null': Permission denied
# chown user:user null
chown: cannot access 'null': Permission denied
# exit
$ ls -ld null
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 0 jan  1  1970 null
```

as you can see, even though the folder is owned by root, root cant access it. also root has execute permissions on my home directory just fine

Comment: "… wich I used once (successfully) to have a `/dev/null` directory […], and after trying to mount again after `fusermount -u`, I get …" – What *exactly* did you do? Post the explicit shell commands you used, not (i.e. not only) your description or interpretation. Is FUSE involved? Does this help? [*How to mount FUSE (e.g. unionfs) so that all users will have access to it?*](https://superuser.com/q/1758100/432690)

Comment: nevermind that. how is it possible that root can't acess it? it has access permissions on my home directory, and even i cant acess it. yes, fuse is involved. see other question. i do not care about other users.

Comment: I may be able to explain, I may be able to help you make it work, but only if I know what exact command you run as what user.

Comment: Did you use `-o allow_other` when mounting the FUSE file system? Or is `user_allow_other` in `/etc/fuse.conf`? Does https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17402/why-does-root-get-permission-denied-when-accessing-fuse-directory answer your question?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski i ran `./nullfs ~/null`, as root, and after rebooting my system it's still there.